# Fun Logic to minus date with date and get the diffdate vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, math, logic

Ok I cannot think of a algorithm to do this using vb.net.

so here is the 3 variable

```
Dim DateFrom as date = '01/09/2015'

Dim DateNow as date = Date.Now

Dim Holiday() as date '' <-- List of holiday dates
```

So what I want to do is I want to get the "Day" diffdate From DateFrom and DateNow and excluding the minus the date in the Holiday() array and also saturday Sunday.

so let say my **DateFrom is '01/09/2015' which is Tuesday** and my
 **DateNow is '09/09/2015' which is also tuesday** and inside the **Holiday() array there's '4/09/2015' Friday**.  the **output of diffdate is suppose to be 5** Day since since (**DateNow ---Difference Day minus Holiday()array and also minus saturday and sunday -- DateFrom)**

I scratches my head about 152.5 times and still cannot find the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem using something like this:

```
Dim intTotalDays As Integer = 0

Dim dtStartDate As New DateTime(2015, 10, 1)
Dim dtEndDate As New DateTime(2015, 10, 31)

Dim Holidays As DateTime() = {
    New DateTime(2015, 10, 15),
    New DateTime(2015, 10, 17)
}

For i As Integer = 0 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtStartDate, dtEndDate)

    Dim dtDay As DateTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, i, dtStartDate)

    If Not dtDay.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday And Not dtDay.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday And Not Holidays.Contains(dtDay) Then
        intTotalDays += 1
    End If

Next i

MsgBox(intTotalDays)
```

Comment: Thanks i think this is just what i wanted :D thank you.

Comment: actually datediff is not exist on vb.net but nvrm i made a function for that hahah

Comment: no, it exists: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx. you need Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace which is usually added as default in a new project.

Comment: check this link if you have any problems with Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w4tctcf.aspx

Comment: ty tezzo! it really helps.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to determine the number of working-days between two dates?

You can use following LINQ query:

```
Dim DateFrom As Date = #9/1/2015#
Dim Holiday() As Date = {#9/4/2015#}
Dim Weekend() As DayOfWeek = {DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday}

Dim days As Int32 = (Date.Today - DateFrom).Days + 1 '+ 1 to include end day '
Dim workingDaysBetween =
    From d In Enumerable.Range(0, days)
    Let day = DateFrom.AddDays(d)
    Where Not Weekend.Contains(day.DayOfWeek) AndAlso Not Holiday.Contains(day)

Dim countDays As Int32 = workingDaysBetween.Count()
```

Comment: thank you for this. i don't usually used linq but thanks :))